# generating Paraphrases of English text using PPDB

Tags: python, python-2.7, ppdb

I need to generate paraphrase of an english sentence using the PPDB paraphrase database

I have downloaded the datasets from the [website](http://paraphrase.org/#/).

Comment: You really need to describe what you've tried.

Comment: PPDB looks like a corpus you'd use to train a paraphrase algorithm, not a tool you'd use directly.  Paraphrasing is a pretty hard NLP problem.  It doesn't look like they've exposed their algorithm, other than it's description in their paper.

Answer (score 2):

I would say your first step needs to be reducing the problem into more manageable components. Second figure out whether you want to paraphrase on a one-to-one, lexical, syntactical, phrase or combination basis. To inform this decision I would take one sentence and paraphrase it myself in order to get an idea of what I am looking for. Next I would start writing a parser for the downloaded data. Then I would remove the stopwords and incorporate a part-of-speech tagger like the ones included in spaCy or nltk for your example phrase.

Since they seem to give you all the information needed to make a successive dictionary filter that is where I would start. I would write a filter which found the parts of speech for each word in my sentence in the [LHS] column of the dataset and select a source that matches the word while minimizing/maximizing the value of 1 feature (like minimizing WordLenDiff) which in the case of "businessnow" <- "business now" = -1.5. Keeping track of the target feature you will then have a basic paraphrased sentence.

using this strategy your output could turn:

```
"the business uses 4 gb standard."
sent_score = 0
```

into:

```
"businessnow uses 4gb standard"
sent_score = -3
```

After you have a basic example the you can start exploring feature selection algorithms in like those in scikit-learn, etc. and incorporate word alignment. But I would seriously cut down on the scope of the problem and increase it gradually. In the end, how you approach the problem it depends on what the designated use is and how functional it needs to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any implementation available so I can test. I like the approach and I will be trying it on myself too. But need some basic understanding using the implementation. Hope to hear from you.

Comment: There is likely no 1 encompassing example. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: a bit confused with the part of tagging and ppdb. How are they correlated? That is why I asked for a reference with respect to your answer. I hope my question for reference does not offend you.

Comment: So can you help me with some reference to your answer? It will great and will accept your answer for sure.... Look forward to hearing from you soon

Comment: Don't worry you did not offend me. On the home page for the PPDB it gives an example in which the LHS field = [VBN]. The best I can figure is that this is a code reference for verbs as seen here: https://cs.nyu.edu/grishman/jet/guide/PennPOS.html . But I can't be positive without checking all of them. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Ok, I got the tagging part.. it is pretty simple. Thank you for explaining it to me. even after tagging the sentence, is there anything that will help me generate the PPDB based paraphrase of a sentence. I have researched a lot but may be I missed. Do you have anything in your mind related to that?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. Just, tag a sentence -> look for matching ppdb tags -> look for the word among the source words -> replace the word if a certain condition is met. I honestly had never heard of ppdb til now. This github lib may help understand how to construct the conditions: https://github.com/summanlp/textrank

Comment: Great.. That helped.